# setAttribute is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am using `setAttribue` as below. Its working only for first time and after that the changing value is showing the `alert` but not setting with `document.getElementById("to").setAttribute("value", selValue);`

```
document.getElementById("listcontact").onchange = function () {
    var selIndex = document.getElementById("listcontact").selectedIndex;
    var selValue = document.getElementById("listcontact").options[selIndex].innerHTML;
    var contactVal = selValue.split(';');      
    var phone = contactVal[2];  

    alert(phone);
    document.getElementById("to").setAttribute("value", selValue);
    selIndex = "";
    selValue = "";
    phone = "";
    selValue = "";
};
```

Why is this not working as I expect and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

The `value` attribute sets the *initial* value, not the *current* value.

Assign something to the `value` property instead.

```
document.getElementById("to").value = selValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
document.getElementById("to").value = selValue;
```