# The color of and <input type="color"> element on a page DOESN'T match its value attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a personnal exercise where I create a small app to allow users to update colors of different parts of an SVG using the `<input type = "color">` element.

The SVG I am playing with is a simple cloud drawings with writing in it. You can modify 3 parts: cloud's stroke color, cloud's fill color and writing's color.

See it live:

1. **live**: https://argonathmos.github.io/SVGfun/
2. **code:** https://github.com/argonathmos/SVGfun

It is a simple UI with 3 areas:

1. A **Random** button that applies random colors to each parts of the
   SVG.
2. Three `<input type="color">` element for each part of the SVG to
   modify each colors by hand.
3. A **Download** button that allows the
   user to export the SVG with the custom colors applyied to it.

Here is what I notice that bothers me and don't know how to fix yet:

- When I click "random", the SVG colors are updated, as well as the value of the `<input type="color">` elements, as well as the **color of the  element on the page** (ie the **little squares** color matches the colors of the associated SVG section).
- When I apply a color individually through the `<input type="color">` element the color of the SVG is updated as well as the value of the `<input type="color">` element, and so is **the color of the input color element on the page (the little square)**.
- **But** If I click "random" after having already selected a color from the color picker by hand:
  The SVG colors are updated, the value attribute of the `<input type="color">` elements as well, but the color of the  element on the page doesn't update its stays the same as the previously hand picked color. **(ie the little square color DOESN'T match the color of the associated SVG section eventhough the value attribute of the  element does.)**

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Code relevant to your problem belongs _directly_ into your question, in text form and properly formatted, or as an executable Stack Snippet, in cases where that makes sense. Please do not _just_ provide the code on an external platform - when it disappears there, the question here will lose all context.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] here in the question. Off-site links will not be useful in the future when you've fixed this, so nobody else can banefit from a solution - not other visitors who come here with a similar problem, not even you if somebody comes in with a potentially better solution.

Comment: Duplicate of [`setAttribute` is not working in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407009/setattribute-is-not-working-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be, that you are using

```
 strokeColorInput.setAttribute('value',strokeColor);
```

to update the value of your color input fields. That is able to set the color for fields you did not already make an explicit choice in, but once you did, it doesn’t work as expected any more.

(This is probably a manifestation of the well-known *attribute vs property* problem/issue here, see [What is the difference between properties and attributes in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/what-is-the-difference-between-properties-and-attributes-in-html))

Make that

```
 strokeColorInput.value = strokeColor;
```

instead, and it appears to be working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and the relevant explanations! 
It solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change `strokeColorInput.setAttribute`, `fillColorInput.setAttribute`, `pathColorInput.setAttribute` to:

```
strokeColorInput.value = strokeColor;
fillColorInput.value = fillColor;
pathColorInput.value = uniquePathcolor;
```

as you are updating HTML values. `.setAttribute` is for CSS attribute values.